How to write with PyFlink/Flink into Apache Iceberg on amazon s3 with Table API?
settings = EnvironmentSettings.new_instance().in_streaming_mode().build()
t_env = TableEnvironment.create(environment_settings=settings)


catalog_name = "glue_catalog"
staging_database_name = "source"
dest_database_name = "dest"
staging_table = "source_iceberg_partitioned_hourly"
dest_table = "new_iceberg_table"
warehouse_path = "s3:path....."

t_env.execute_sql(
    f"""
    CREATE CATALOG {catalog_name} WITH (
        'type'='iceberg',
        'catalog-impl'='org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog',
        'warehouse'='{warehouse_path}',
        'aws.region'='eu-central-1',
        'io-impl'='org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO'
    )
    """
)

t_env.execute_sql(f"USE CATALOG {catalog_name};")
t_env.execute_sql(f"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {staging_database_name}")
t_env.execute_sql(f"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {dest_database_name}")
t_env.execute_sql(f"USE {dest_database_name};")

staging_table_full = f"{catalog_name}.{staging_database_name}.{staging_table}"
dest_table_full = f"{catalog_name}.{dest_database_name}.{dest_table}"`


create_table_statement = f"""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {dest_table} (
"""
Columns....

)
PARTITIONED BY (collector_minute)
WITH (
    'type'='iceberg',
    'format-version'='2',
    'write.format.default'='parquet',
    'write.metadata.delete-after-commit.enabled'='true',
    'write.distribution-mode'='hash',
    'path'='{warehouse_path}'
)
"""
t_env.execute_sql(create_table_statement)

latest_snapshot_id = "12345678901234567890"

t_env.execute_sql(
    f"""
    INSERT INTO {query_table_full}
    SELECT *, 
        MINUTE(collector_tstamp) AS collector_minute
    FROM {staging_table_full} /*+ OPTIONS('streaming' = 'true', 'monitor-interval' = '10s', 'start-snapshot-id' = '{latest_snapshot_id}') */
    """
)

Im using the Image flink:1.16.1-scala_2.12
with these jars:
bundle-2.20.18.jar
flink-shaded-hadoop-2-uber-2.8.3-10.0.jar
flink-sql-connector-hive-2.3.9_2.12-1.16.1.jar
guava-30.1-jre.jar
hadoop-common-2.8.3.jar
iceberg-flink-runtime-1.16-1.3.1.jar
Im basically aiming to read from one iceberg table and to write on the second iceberg table as soon as new data is there.
Usually i would use spark for this but i wanted to try out flink and if the data is written faster
So what im actually doing is
jobmanager.sh start and taskmanager.sh start at the beginning
waiting for some seconds and then executing my pyflink.py
Its able to actually create the Iceberg-table in which it want to write.
In the logs i see that its also able to scan the source-iceberg table and to print out the name of the latest manifest.json of the source table.
Sadly at this points nothing happens anymore, its not writing data into the table so im wondering if this Insert is maybe wrong.
CPU and Mem are actually showing the whole time some activity (cpu 50%)
I could find only examples where the Insert is used with example row data. So im not quite sure if a Insert can happen with a Select together.
Dont think that its due to resources since im running it on my m1 and gave him all i have :D

I had a similar problem, so I enabled checkpoints and set the max checkpoint timeout to 60 seconds. Data started being inserted into my Iceberg table.
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.20/api/python/reference/pyflink.datastream/api/pyflink.datastream.stream_execution_environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.enable_checkpointing.html?highlight=enable_check#pyflink.datastream.stream_execution_environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.enable_checkpointing
